# Reading file in internal directory in a rooted Android phone

Tags: android

How do I read the contents of a file stored in the internal directory in a rooted Android phone?

I am using the following but it is not working, I am getting blank:

```
    filePath = "/data/";
    File file = new File(filePath, "test.conf");
    StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
try {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        text.append(line);
        text.append('\n');
    }
}
catch (IOException e) {

}
return text.toString();
```

Any idea what's the issue?

Comment: Have you requested and allowed root privileges?

Comment: But isn't it already rooted? I only check whether I can "su" and if can then read the file.

Comment: Your phone may be rooted, but your process still needs to request superuser permissions. See this blog post on how to do this: http://www.stealthcopter.com/blog/2010/01/android-requesting-root-access-in-your-app/

Comment: Better You post the error what you got!

Answer (score 0):

Using the example from the link given by @Blade0rz, I have modified it to get a file from internal memory. Basically, I am copying the contents into a test file on the sdcard. And subsequently, I could do anything with it and root access is not required after which.

```
           Process p;
           try {
               // Preform su to get root privledges
               p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");

               // Attempt to write a file to a root-only
               DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(p.getOutputStream());

               String path =  Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/test.txt";
               os.writeBytes("cat /data/test.conf >" + path +"\n");
               // Close the terminal
               os.writeBytes("exit\n");
               os.flush();

              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), path, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

               try {
                   p.waitFor();
                   if (p.exitValue() != 255) {
                       // TODO Code to run on success
                       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Phone is Rooted.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                   }
                   else {
                       // TODO Code to run on unsuccessful
                       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Phone is Not Rooted.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                   }
               } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                   // TODO Code to run in interrupted exception
                   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Phone is Not Rooted.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               }
           } catch (IOException e) {
               // TODO Code to run in input/output exception
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Phone is Not Rooted.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           }
```